# Slickgrid text selection while refreshing data

Tags: slickgrid

I have a slickgrid table that I refresh with new data every couple of seconds. If set enableTextSelectionOnCells to allow the user to select text in a cell, currently the selection is removed when the table refreshes.

Is there a way to persist user cell-selection during a grid.setData(newData) call?

Answer (score 0):

you can use goToCell after setting data as follows,

grid.gotoCell(row, cell, forceEdit);
grid.gotoCell(0, 0, true); // it will take you the 1st row and 1st cell and will make it editable.

Answer (score 0):

Use dataView.syncGridSelection(grid, true);

dataView.syncGridSelection(grid, true); function will preserve the row selection even after adding new row to the grid. Later U can check for the active cell and make it active Try it

Comment: Ok, but add this to your answer. Comments are not eternal. They may be deleted.